# What happens when you call UserPrincipal.Current.GivenName from a non AD account?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, error-handling, asp.net-mvc-5, active-directory, userprincipal

Trying to set up a custom User check as follows:

```
currentSessionUser = new User() //Nope, lets pull information from the Active Directory
{
    FirstName = UserPrincipal.Current.GivenName,
    LastName = UserPrincipal.Current.Surname,
    Username = UserPrincipal.Current.SamAccountName,
    AccountState = 0
};
```

What happens when your client is a non-AD Account or, say, a mobile device?

How do I catch for errors here?

Comment: The 'Current' property takes current user SID from process\thread token and query information from AD via LDAP protocol in case of AD account or from local machine using WinNT protocol if it's local account. If the account SID cannot be found it throws NoMatchingPrincipalException, If the SID information cannot be retrieved the function will throw PrincipalOperationException. I do have doubts that S.DS.AM is supported on mobile devices (even on Windows phone)

Comment: So checking for null values in the current property would be the best way to handle non AD devices? I am not too concerned with actually handling mobile devices- moreso locking out devices that can't be authenticated by a simple username check.

Comment: I can claim only, that if you run the process under the local account on a Windows-based computer and call the 'Current' property most of values will have null values (UserPrincipal.Current.SamAccountName will be set)

Comment: Just to make sure we are on the same page. What I suppose is that you have an ASP.NET application that runs on IIS (may be a standalone workstation or joined to a domain). UserPrincipal.Current will return you the user which launches your process (app pool in IIS by default or specified in web.config), or user account under which current thread is impersonating under

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To properly catch the exception that can be thrown- `PrincipalServerDownException`
You just need to encapsulate the area that is trying to query the userprincipal in a catch block for the aforementioned exception type.

```
    try
    {
        u = new User
        {
            FirstName = UserPrincipal.Current.GivenName,
            LastName = UserPrincipal.Current.Surname,
            Username = UserPrincipal.Current.SamAccountName,
            Guid = UserPrincipal.Current.Guid.ToString(),
            CanEditHidData = true,
            CanEditQaData = true,
            AccountState = 0 //0=Unlocked 1=HigherPrivs Privs 2=Locked
        };
        return u;
    }
    catch (PrincipalServerDownException e)
    {
        u = new User
        {
            FirstName = "Guest",
            LastName = "Account",
            Username = "guest",
            Guid = Guid.Empty.ToString(),
            CanEditHidData = false,
            CanEditQaData = false,
            AccountState = 3 //0=Unlocked 1=HigherPrivs Privs 2=Locked 3=Guest
        };
        ViewBag.ErrorMessage = e.Message;
        View("Error");
        return u;
    }
```